# GPU with hevc AND crf encoding on ffmpeg?

Tags: graphics-cards, linux

Since I have my son I record looooots of 4k videos. By default it take about 400 MB per minute. Thoses videos are recorded with an iPhone or a Galaxy S7. So the phones are not powerful enough to compress with a better bitrate.

My i7 2600k with ffmpeg is able to encode about 2 FPS. It's way too long. So I am looking for a graphical card able to accelerate encoding in HEVC / x265. I have notice lot's of NVENC GPU, but they seams to be made to be able to encode in real time with the drawback of having big file size : with GPU acceleration the CRF option of ffmpeg is usually not available. Because it use an other process and the compression is not as powerful than with a software encoding. So the file is not as tiny as it would be with software compression.

So is there GPU card able to encode in HEVC with the CRF option of ffmpeg to keep a specific quality for a better video size please? I don't need real time encoding, but 2 FPS is really too slow.

I can use other encoder than ffmpeg as long as they run under Linux.

If I can stay around 250 €, maximum 500€ it would be nice. Because I will buy this GPU only for the video encoding.

Thank you,

A.

Comment: "but they seams to be made to be able to encode in real time with the drawback of having big file size." I'm confused as to what you're saying here. The final export has a large file size? That doesn't make sense. And 53Mb/s is awfully high; why such a high bitrate? Perhaps this could be turned down? What GPU do you currently have, if any? What's your budget? Are you bound to FFmpeg? Do you care about the lack of flexibility that comes with GPU encoding?

Comment: OK, I add more information about what you asked